# How do I sort google text- and image search results by date?

Tags: search, google-api, search-engine

We would like to set up a search site where it is possible to sort the search results in "time of publishing" - date:hour:minute - both for text and for images.
Is that possible to build with a professional API from Google?

The problem is that if you today select to show text search results and select ”tools", ”last year” and then select to display them ”sort by date”, only a fraction of the results are displayed in google.
Also results from both text and image "date"-searches are displayed randomly. (1 day old, 5 days old, 3 days old)
Is it possible to somehow show all results sorted by date and time?

I'm open for suggestions using other search engines and programming. 
Thanks!